# How to set a new TextInput value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Before I was changing the text input with the local state. Like this:

```
         state = {name: ''}
         ...
         <AddEditFormInputs
            onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })}
            textStateValue={this.state.name}
          />
```

This is the component and above is how I call it:

```
const AddEditFormInputs = ({
  onChangeText,
  textStateValue,
}) => (
  <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
    <TextInput
      value={textStateValue}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
    />
  </View>
);
```

But now I need to do the same with Redux. I am attempting to do it like this:

```
  <AddEditFormInputs
    onChangeText={name => editPassengerDataActionActionHandler({ name })}
    textStateValue={editPassengerData.name}
  />
...
export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      editPassengerData: store.popupsModals.editPassengerData,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      editPassengerDataActionActionHandler: data => {
        dispatch(editPassengerDataAction(data));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(PassengerFormModal);
```

I see that the input contains the value of `editPassengerData.name`, but when I try to change that value, it returns to the old value, like if I type something it deletes what I typed. I know this is maybe because I am mutating the data. But then, what can I do to change the value of that input?

Should it be only with local state or can I do it with Redux?

This is the TextInput I am using -> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Comment: I would recommend using redux-form : https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form

Answer (score 0):

In the words of someone better than me

> Use React for ephemeral state that doesn’t matter to the app globally and doesn’t mutate in complex ways. For example, a toggle in some UI element, a form input state. Use Redux for state that matters globally or is mutated in complex ways. For example, cached users, or a post draft.
>     - Dan Abramov

Comment: There is a functionality I need to achieve. I know I don't have to mutate data. But I need to achieve something and there should be a way...

Comment: yeah, you're using redux in a form, that is exactly what the creator of redux told you not to do, use formik